# Express and Socket.io with Nginx reverse proxy - Size limitation?

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx

I have a simple Express + Socket.io app being funnelled through an Nginx reverse proxy. This app has been working fine for months, but has recently increased a little in usage.

Part of the application has a section where users can submit data, and then an admin panel where that data can be viewed. The admin panel is served by Socket.io, so it updates live as new data comes in.

When the admin panel is loaded, it sends an initial request to the server to grab data, and the server checks if the user is authenticated and then sends data back, aggregating it like so:

```
var data = {
    listOfBRSystems: listOfBRSystems,
    submittedReports: submittedReports,
    coloredSystems: coloredSystems
}
socket.emit('adminData', data);
```

This works fine up until a certain point, when it just suddenly stops sending that data when the client requests it. The client console shows the error:

```
 WebSocket connection to https://x.xxx/ failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

However, if I remove **any** data from the three variables, it then works fine again until more data is submitted, pushing it over some threshold. I can't figure out what or where this threshold actually is.

Here's some statistics of the data variable, based on an export of it just as it starts to fail:

```
Size: 125,748 bytes
Count of Objects: 1098
```

I would estimate that it starts to fail around the ~125,500 byte mark. I can't see anything special about these two items that could cause the socket to fail, but there could be extra overhead by socket.io or something pushing up the byte count.

Is there a limitation in Nginx, Express or Socket.io that can cause this kind of issue?

Comment: Does the same problem occur without nginx in front?

Comment: If not, does it occur with something else in front, like HAProxy?